# Using GraphServiceClient in MVC application hangs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I've been studying other posts with simular or the same issue but I can't figure out a solution to this issue. I'm using a clean Web MVC sample application in VS2022 and the latest version of Microsoft.Graph (5.22). The same code works perfect in a console application. It's my understanding that it's some kind of a deadlock issue. Here is the code:

```
public async Task<string> GetSiteId()
{
    string tenantID = "xxxxxxxx-58a7-4ade-a233-740e8f251911";
    string appID = "xxxxxxx-0962-4c42-b14f-00505a836262";
    string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxvBcm7ZrKCGevVWOG~ex7blIpfWObTPcJN";

    var credentials = new Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantID,
        appID,
        clientSecret);


    var context = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
    var response = credentials.GetTokenAsync(context).Result;
    // Respone is fine so far....

    m_graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

    var domain = "xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com";
    var path = "/sites/root";
    
    // **** It hangs here ****
    var site = await m_graphServiceClient.Sites[$"{domain}:{path}"].GetAsync(); 

    return site.Id;
}

public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = this.GetSiteId().Result;

    return View();
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: since you said `application hangs`, could you pls debug your code in visual studio to see if there's anything wrong between the variables? By the way, could you pls change all the `.Result` to `await` and test again?

Comment: I tried with GetSiteId().ConfigureAwait(true); and it doesn't hang in the main thread, but it still hangs in the task. Looking att Tasks in VS you can see the status of the different Tasks and there seems to be a Scheduled task ID 102 that the other tasks are waitning for (Last line from output from Tasks in debugger) 
Not Flagged  102 Scheduled [Scheduled and waiting to run] Async: <SendAsync>d__5

Comment: Problem solved: I needed to make the event as async like: public async Task<ActionResult> Contact() and then use await when calling the method. Maybe this could help other someone else having the same problem.